# Concatenate character to __VA_ARGS__ in a macro redefining printf

Tags: c, macros

I'm developing an embedded application that uses a library for interfacing with a SPI NAND memory chip.  The library provided uses a print function in which I, as the applications developer, must override for my specific platform.

For instance, they use the function `printf_` extensively in their code.

I redefine it as such, to get the print function to print over the serial interface

```
#define printf_(...) serial.printf(__VA_ARGS__)
```

It works fine, except that on this platform, you need to supply a carriage return ("\r") for a newline.  So right now, when the library is called, the formatting is horrible.

I'd like to append a "\r" to the end of whatever is supplied to the print function.  Like

```
#define printf_(...) serial.printf(__VA_ARGS__##"\r")
```

Obviously that doesn't work.

I'm really not familiar with, and have sort of a hard time understanding variadic functions in C, so this would provide me with a little learning opportunity if I could figure this out, or at least I would learn if this is not possible.

I also can't just wrap the function using `va_list`s and `vsprintf`s because my platform does not support this (and I'd rather redefine it in a macro, as a performance/stylistic choice, personally).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are there `\n` in the string to be printed that you want to be `\r` or do you just want an `\r` output after each `printf`?

Comment: It has to be both `\r` and `\n`.  I'd like to use the printf_ function for all parts of my code, and I'm too used to using \n.  So basically, if I write something like `printf_("Hello\n");`, I'd like it to get redefined to `"Hello\n\r"`.

Comment: Normally, you generate `\r\n` for the CRLF line ending on DOS, and many Internet standards also use CRLF for line endings.  Your proposed use of `\n\r` is unusual — are you sure you have the sequence correct?  Actually, it is easier if you're correct, then you can use `#define printf_(fmt, ...) serial.printf(fmt "\r", __VA_ARGS__)` to get most of the way to what you need.  That won't work if the format string is not a string literal, nor if there are no arguments other than the format string.  There are possibly compiler-specific workarounds for the 'no extra arguments'.

Comment: You might be able to deal with the 'append `\r`' requirement with: `#define printf_(...) (serial.printf(__VA_ARGS__), serial.printf("\r"))` which calls `printf()` twice to send the original data plus the CR.  And so the list goes on.  I used the comma operator because it guarantees sequential execution (unlike `+` which I showed briefly); it could lose error information, but usually won't, and does lose the length information. If that matters, you have much more work to do anyway.  You could use various other alternatives, again depending in part on which compiler you use.

Comment: If you like one of the answers given, please go ahead and accept one of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could just output `'\r'` after the call to serial.printf ?

```
#define printf_(...) do { serial.printf(__VA_ARGS__); serial.printf("\r"); } while(0)
```

Comment: Yep, didn't think of that.  Thank you for pointing this easy solution out!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with other users that your requirement of CR coming *after* LF is quite strange, and I have a strong suspicion you mean for it to be CRLF, not LFCR. Regardless, I will help you with your original requirement of appending CR to the string.

It is going to be incredibly difficult to perform this operation in a one-liner macro. Alternatively, you could use a nasty-looking multi-line macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define printf_(format, args...)                                        \
do {                                                                    \
    int _len_orig = strlen(format);                                     \
    /* strlen doesn't consider newline. Check for that. */              \
    if ( format[_len_orig] == '\n' )                                    \
        _len_orig++;                                                    \
                                                                        \
    /* len_orig + 2 to make space for null terminator and '\r' */       \
    unsigned _new_size = _len_orig + 2;                                 \
    char* _new_str  = calloc(_new_size, 1);                             \
    strncpy( _new_str, format, _len_orig );                             \
    _new_str[_new_size-2] = '\r';                                       \
                                                                        \
    /* Print out the raw hex of the string to prove it worked */        \
    int _i;                                                             \
    for( _i = 0; _i < _new_size; _i++)                                  \
        printf("%02x ", _new_str[_i]);                                  \
    printf("\n");                                                       \
    free(_new_str);                                                     \
} while(0)


int main(){

    char* str = "@@@@\n";
    printf_( str );

    return 0;
}
```

In my macro, I have not used your serial.printf function but rather made some short code that prints out the hexidecimal values of the concatenated string for proof that the logic works.

#### Explanation

- Macros are required to appear as a single line to the C Preprocessor. The additions of `\` at the end of each macro line escape the newline character.
- [gcc allows for named arguments in your macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.1/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html). Here, `format` describes the format string you would normally pass to printf, and `args...` is the variable argument name for "everything else" you would pass into printf. I do not reference args in this example, but you will certainly want to modify my example in your final code to include it. Your call to printf would look something like `serial.printf( _new_str, args);`
- Multi-line macros are kind of nasty in that you need to do some trickery to get them to appear as normal functions to the human programmer. The need for enclosing the macro in a do-while [is nicely discussed here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Multi-statement_Macro). The linked page is meant for C++, but it applies to C as well.

If you copy my code, compile, and run it, this is the output:

```
[clipp@h2ologin3:~]$ ./a.out
40 40 40 40 0a 0d 00
```

Here, this ASCII dump is showing us that 4 `@` symbols were copied, followed by `\n`, `\r`, and finally `\0`.

There is also a strong case for instead writing this as an inline C function. You say that your system doesn't support va_list etc. so if that is true, then a  macro may be the only choice.

QED.

Comment: The carriage return and the newline do two specific things in this embedded platform, and the order in which they're sent doesn't matter.  This solution you proposed above... I hope I never run into any of that in real life...